# SELECT only access to SQL Server with access execute any Scalar UDF

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I'm looking for the best way (best practice) and/or least administrative effort to allow a user read-only (SELECT only) access to a database **and** use any scalar UDFs defined in the database.  I can accomplish the first part of my task by assigning only the db_datareader role to the users Login. However the user cannot see or execute any of the Scalar UDF's in this database (SQL Server 2008 R2).  I know you can run GRANT EXECUTE ON My_UDF TO MY_USER and it will work and it will allow the user access. However, there are two problems with this.  First of all we have hundreds of UDFs and we would need to loop through all of them giving the user EXECUTE to every UDF.  Secondly, whenever a new UDF is created we would need to issue this command again to this READ-ONLY user.

The goal is to give the user as little permission as possible but still allow them to do SELECT's (no UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE) and be able to use any UDFs in their SELECTS.

Comment: I would suggest you have a third problem which is a much bigger issue, you have hundreds of scalar UDFs. Scalar UDFs are notoriously awful for performance. You should look into converting as many as these as possible to inline table valued functions. Do not confuse that with multi-statement table functions which are actually worse than scalar functions. If you are deadset on sticking with these udfs maybe you can create a schema for them. That would make access easier to deal with.

Comment: I agree it's a problem but one that I can't do anything about.  These are generated by our ERP system (we are in Higher Ed) and the user's have become dependent on them. Since the ERP creates and consumes them I would be hesitant to move these into another schema.

Comment: Ugh. Then about all you can do is use sql to generate your permissions for you. Just query sys.objects and build the sql statements. You can then just copy and paste (to selectively remove rows) or create a big dynamic sql statement and run it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 and above, you can try `GRANT EXECUTE TO [MyDomain\MyUser]`

This would give `Execute` permissions to the user at the database level including any stored procedures.

Comment: That is way too broad for this situation. This would give the user way more access than desired.

Comment: I agree with Sean. More authority than is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from putting them in their own schema (which, from what you say above, doesn't seem feasible), I think you're stuck with granting the permissions at an object level. Luckily, this isn't too hard with some powershell and elbow grease.

```
import-module sqlps;

$perms = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ObjectPermissionSet;
$perms.Execute = $true;

$srv = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server 'yourServer'
$db = $srv.databases['yourDb'];
foreach ($f in $db.UserDefinedFunctions) {
    $f.grant($perms, 'some grantee')
}
```